# May I destroy a mutexattr object before the mutex that was initialized with this mutexattr is used?

Tags: c, attributes, pthreads, posix, mutex

Consider the following code:

```
pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
pthread_mutexattr_setrobust(&attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST);

pthread_mutex_t mut;
pthread_mutex_init(&mut, &attr);

pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&attr);

pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
```

Is this code valid?

If the mutex is allowed to contain references to the attribute object it was initialized with, then I suppose I may not call `pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&attr)` before using the mutex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutexattr_init) say:

> After a mutex attributes object has been used to initialize one or more mutexes, any function affecting the attributes object (including destruction) shall not affect any previously initialized mutexes.

So your code is valid (but don't forget to check the potential error of these functions).